# Getting SQL file from physical phone in device monitor not working?

Tags: android, android-device-monitor

I have noticed in the android device monitor when I try to access the data folder so I can pull the sql file of my application that is running on my physical phone it does not work but when accessing the application through an emulator it does work. Obviously running the application on the emulator is much more time consuming and I need to present this sqlite data in a timed viva so I can't really be waiting for an emulator.

I was wondering why this is happening as I have allowed debugging and while it does not ask for any more checks on security the device monitor will not open the data folder, when clicked the arrowhead next to the folder disappears then reappears after a few seconds but I can still access every other folder with a drop-down arrow next to it.

Answer (score 0):

If your device is not rooted, you cannot access your app's data file. Try to use following code snippet in any of your `Activity` to copy the file to sdcard.

```
public static void copyDataFile() {
    File dataDir = getFilesDir().getParentFile();
    File target = new File(dataDir, "/* relative path to your sql file */");
    File out = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/* new file name */");
    copyFile(target, out);
}

public static void copyFile(File in, File out) {
    if (in.exists()) {
        if (!out.exists()) {
            try {
                out.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        FileInputStream is = null;
        FileOutputStream os = null;
        try {
            is = new FileInputStream(in);
            os = new FileOutputStream(out);
            byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
            int l = 0;
            while ((l = is.read(buf)) > 0) {
                os.write(buf, 0, l);
            }
            os.flush();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (is != null) {
                    is.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                if (os != null) {
                    os.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```